# Prettier code formatting is not splitting classNames in JSX or HTML

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, prettier

I have the Prettier VSCode extension enabled and my local .prettierrc file has `"printWidth": 70` as one of the options, however, when I have a long list of classNames in my JSX (or plain HTML) file, Prettier does not honor the `printWidth` setting and lets the list of classes run on indefinitely without breaking the line. This is only an issue because I use Headwind, which is a Tailwind class sorting extension and when running `Headwind:Sort` it takes my multi line classes and puts them back on one line. Running `Prettier:Format` should then split this long line up again, but alas, it does not.

Example starting code:

```
<div className="flex flex-col w-full p-6 border-r-2 items-start
w-1/2 bg-white rounded shadow h-1/3 hover:bg-slate-50 active:bg-slate-100">
```

Then `Headwind:Sort` is run which puts all the classes on a single, long line:

```
<div className="flex flex-col w-full p-6 border-r-2 items-start w-1/2 bg-white rounded shadow h-1/3 hover:bg-slate-50 active:bg-slate-100">
```

Then after running `Prettier:Format` all of the code is *still* one one line even though my `printWidth` option is set to 70 characters.

Is there a way to get Prettier to split these lines up again? And if not, is there another solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Did Prettier break up any of your long strings before you added Headwind? Can you turn Headwind off and test this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't currently a solution for this directly from Prettier.  But [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918#issuecomment-851049185) is what the creator of Tailwind does to get around this.

TLDR: Use [Headwind](https://github.com/ryanhhhh/headwind) in VSCode or just enable Word Wrap in your editor

Comment: Ended up enabling Word Wrap which was the simplest way to get the wrapping to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt refer my answer below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75498001/12719767

Answer (score 3):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71947142/12719767) mentions a [link](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/10918#issuecomment-851049185) where the creator of Tailwind mentions about a plugin could be released in future and they [released](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/automatic-class-sorting-with-prettier) prettier-plugin-tailwindcss plugin 4 months before the accepted answer is written. i think lot of people are unaware of it so i'm writing this answer.

---

Here is my simplied answer from my public [gist](https://gist.github.com/Nivethan-Ar/2375bf451d4c30148916b59c7e0c51c0)

1. install prettier

   ```
   pnpm add -D prettier
   ```
2. To automatically sort tailwind classes with prettier

   ```
   pnpm add -D prettier-plugin-tailwindcss
   ```
3. Create a `.prettierrc.json` file in your root directory

   ```
   touch .prettierrc.json
   ```
4. Add the installed plugin to your .prettierrc.json config file

   ```
   {
     "trailingComma": "es5",
     "semi": true,
     "tabWidth": 2,
     "singleQuote": true,
     "jsxSingleQuote": true,
     "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]

   }
   ```

---

#### OP's code before auto tailwind class sorting

```html
<div className="flex flex-col w-full p-6 border-r-2 items-start
w-1/2 bg-white rounded shadow h-1/3 hover:bg-slate-50 active:bg-slate-100">
```

#### OP's code after sorted by prettier-plugin-tailwindcss

This plugin sort the classes in the following order

`base layer classes | components layer classes | utility layer classes`

```html
<div className='flex h-1/3 w-full w-1/2 flex-col items-start rounded border-r-2 bg-white p-6 shadow hover:bg-slate-50 active:bg-slate-100'></div>
```

---

#### one more cool thing

write your break point prefixes(`md:` `lg:` `xl:`) in new line and manually indent them then the plugin will only sort classes on each line(its not perfect but we almost there )

```html
<div
  className='flex h-1/3 w-full w-1/2 flex-col items-start rounded border-r-2
            md:h-1 md:bg-red-400 md:bg-transparent md:p-1
            lg:h-10 lg:bg-blue-400 lg:p-5'
></div>
```

Comment: How does that solve the full long lines?

Comment: I use this plugin, but adding breakpoint prefixes doesn't solve the issue